# How to find a deleted calendar that does not show up on APIs explorer?

Tags: google-calendar-api

How can I recover a deleted calendar?  I have searched help forum and tried the suggestions, it does not come up on the APIs explorer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If this is a programming question, please clarify how it is a programming question. It does not seem to be on-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old workaround Google calendar does not have a command for restoring a deleted calendar.

Go to google calendar create a new calendar use the EXACT same name.  It must be exactly the same.   If you are lucky it will still contain the data